# Trying to download Excel in Struts1.3 with Apache Poi. Not working from the second request

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, struts1

Struts_config.xml

```
<action path="/dwnldExcel" type="ntrs.pat.action.DwnExclAction">
</action>
```

rightMenuPanel.jsp

```
<html:link action="dwnldExcel"><img src="resource/excel_icon.png" height="30" width="30"></html:link>
```

xxAction.java

```
   String serverFilePath = "D:\\workbook8.xls";
  //Getting the parameters via session attribute.     
   HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession();
   String filterStr = (String) httpSession.getAttribute("filterStr");
   LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> bzMap = (LinkedHashMap<String,   ArrayList<String>>) httpSession.getAttribute("BizMap");

  //Write to filesytem in server
   writetoFile(serverFilePath, filterStr, bzMap);

  // Read the file from server and stream it
   File downloadFile = new File(serverFilePath);
   String mimeType = getServlet().getServletContext().getMimeType(serverFilePath);
   response.setContentType(mimeType);
   response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());
   response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="+serverFilePath );
   ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
   FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(downloadFile);     
   byte[] outputBuffer  = new byte[4096];
   while(inStream.read(outputBuffer, 0, 4096) != -1){
        out.write(outputBuffer, 0, 4096);
   }
   inStream.close();
   out.flush();
   out.close();

public void writetoFile(String filePath, String filterStr, 
            LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> bizzMap){
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("BusinessDetails");

    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(columnNum);
    cell.setCellValue(celvalue);
    //logic to write the content
    :
    :
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
    wb.close();
}
```

If I comment the read and stream section, a excel gets created correctly based on the filter params in server for all requests, but along with read section - excel gets created only on first request, and further return the same one again in client - debugging shows it doesnt come to this specific action class itself. It doesnt throw any exception also.